# setup route for cakephp3 html url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have `URL` like `article_title_page-c-31-c-2.html`

where I want to map to the articles controller  and action category, where
`article_title_page` can be any value, the number `31` and `2` will be pass as parameter to the action category, and
`-c-` and `-c-` is fixed and is used to show that is should be sent to the article controller and action category, how can I do such a route in `cakephp3.5`?

I try the below in the route file, but problem, it can't differentiate the `-c-`  or `article_title_page-d-31-d-2.html` will also go to the same controller and action, which I want to filter out

```
Router::connect('/:slugc-:id:c-:page.html',
    ['controller'=>'products', 'action'=>'category'],
    ['pass' => array('id','page','slug'), 'id'=>'[\d]+','page'=>'[\d]+'  
    ]
    );
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this locally, but try this:

> /:slug:c1:id:c2:page.html

And match c1 and c2 via regex to be `c-`.